# Sublime multi-select with caps-lock key - How?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, keymapping, sublime-text-plugin

I use Sublime Text's incredible [multi-select feature](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/selection) a lot. I love it. But my `Ctrl` key and pinky finger don't.

Is it possible to map the `caps-lock` key to the `multi-select` feature? If so, how?

I think I could simply remap `caps-lock` to `Ctrl` on my system (Windows 7), but I'm ideally looking for a "Sublime only" approach so that I don't loose caps-lock functionality with other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is not one of Sublime's [bindable keys](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#bindable-keys). However, there are [alternatives](https://www.google.com/#q=windows%20remap%20keys). One that I've heard a lot of good things about is [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com), which uses a script-based approach to [remap keys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm), among many other features. You can set keys to be remapped only when a certain application is active, for example, eliminating your worry about affecting other applications.